# Ways to Convert pcap File to Byte Streams

Tags: python, c, network-programming, packet, pcap

I wonder if there's a way to convert pcap packets to byte streams that are usable in C or Python? That would be the best if the conversion can also be done in C or Python.

What I want to do is to regenerate the packets to do some testings, and due to the framework limitations, it can only be done in C/Python. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used this tool so I cant comment on how good it is, but a quick google search lead me to http://src.carnivore.it/streams/about which seems to have the `pipe` and `dump` function thats seems to do what you want.